# Асинхронность на flask

Tags: flask, асинхронность

Есть приложение flask, которое загружает фотографию на сервер, обрабатывает ее с помощью некой нейросетки и сохраняет новую фотографию в директории, после чего показывает ее пользователю. Задание звучит так: Необходимо чтобы при работе с несколькими пользователями каждый не ждал пока сервер закончит работать с предыдущим пользователем, а задача выполнялась сразу же. Другими словами при наличие двух клиентов на моем сайте выполнение алгоритма достаточно сильно растягивается, нужно сократить это время одновременным выполнением. Что посоветуете?

Comment: [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html)?

Comment: Во-первых, запустить несколько воркеров каким-либо способом. Во-вторых, это не имеет никакого отношения к асинхронности

Comment: Я только учусь) мне так человек, давший это задание объяснил) Каким образом можно запустить несколько воркеров?

Comment: Эта возможность встроена в любом нормальном wsgi-сервере (gunicorn, uwsgi и пр.)